# Ionic "build version" clarification

Tags: ionic-framework, versioning

I am using Ionic Deploy and trying to understand their [versioning format](https://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/#binary-versioning).

I can define if a 'Deploy snapshot' applies to a range of app versions using their control panel in the image below:

[image]

but to which tag in the config.xml file does the "Binary version" correspond? There are all these "versions" in the config.xml file:

```
        android-versionCode="1690" 
        ios-CFBundleVersion="1690" 
       ios-CFBundleVersionString="138"  
       version="1.69"  
       versionCode="1690"
```

?

Moreover, I am not using semantic versioning format for my app, do you think I can switch to this now ? If yes, given the number in my config.xml above, which version should I apply ?